# memory allocation problem while reading a file

Tags: c, malloc, out-of-memory

I'm trying to multiply two matrices stored in a file thus formatted:

```
1 2
2 3
*
-4 1
1 0
```

I do not know initially what the dimension of each matrix is. But I let the user define it or otherwise a default value of `100` is taken.

```
int maxc = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) * atoi(argv[2]) : 100;
```

I can already perform the calculation correctly, but I've noticed that if I enter the dimension `argv[2] = "2"` so that `maxc = 8`, (that should be enough for this example), errors are produced in reading or printing the file. But if I enter `argv[2] = "3"` everything works out fine for this example. Since `maxc` is used to allocate memory here: `matrix = malloc(maxc * sizeof *matrix)`, I suspect the problem could be located on that line. Should I allocate memory also for  `size_t row; size_t col;`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNOP 50 /*Max number of operations allowed */
#define MAXNMATR 20 /*Max number of matrices */

struct m {
    size_t row;
    size_t col;
    double *data;
};

struct m multiply(struct m *A, struct m *B);
void f(double x);
void print_matrix(struct m *A);
void read_file(int maxc, FILE *fp);
void scalar_product(double scalar, struct m *B);
void calculate(struct m *matrix, int nop, int id, char *op);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *file = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "rb") : stdin;

    /* define max dimension of a matrix */
    int maxc = argc > 2 ? atoi(argv[2]) * atoi(argv[2]) : 100;
    read_file(maxc, file);       

    return 0;
}

void read_file(int maxc, FILE *fp) {
    struct m *matrix;
    int id = 0; /* id of a matrix */
    size_t ncol, nrow; /* No of columns of a matrix*/
    ncol = nrow = 0;
    int nop = 0; /*No of operators*/
    int off = 0;
    int i;
    int n;
    double *d;
    char buf[2 * maxc]; /*to store each lines of file */
    char *p = buf;
    char op[MAXNOP];

    for (i = 0; i < MAXNOP; i++)
        op[i] = '?';    

    if (!(matrix = malloc(maxc * sizeof *matrix))) {
        perror("malloc-matrix");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Read file line by line */
    while (fgets(buf, maxc, fp)) {
        if (nrow == 0) {
            /* allocate/validate max no. of matrix */
            d = matrix[id].data = malloc(sizeof(double) * MAXNMATR);
        }     
        /* check if line contains operator */
        if ((!isdigit(*buf) && buf[1] =='\n')) {      
            op[nop++] = *buf;
            matrix[id].col = ncol;
            matrix[id].row = nrow;
            nrow = ncol = 0;
            id++;
            continue;
        } else {
            /* read integers in a line into d */
            while (sscanf(p + off, "%lf%n", d, &n) == 1) {
                d++;
                if (nrow == 0)
                    ncol++;
                off += n;
            }
            nrow++;
            off = 0;
        }
    } /*end of while fgets cycle */

    /* Assign last matrix No of columns and rows */
    matrix[id].col = ncol;
    matrix[id].row = nrow;

    /* Printing the matrices and operations */
    for (i = 0; i <= id; i++) {  
        if (op[i] == '*' || op[i] == '-' || op[i] =='+') {
            print_matrix(&matrix[i]);
            if (op[i-1] != 'i')
                printf("%c\n", op[i]);
            else
                continue;
        } else      
        if (op[i] == '?') {
             print_matrix(&matrix[i]);
        }        
    }

    calculate(matrix, nop, id, op);
}

void calculate(struct m *matrix, int nop, int id, char *op) {    
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= nop; i += 2) {        
        if (op[i] == '*' && op[i+1] == '?') {
             if (matrix[i].row == 1 && matrix[i].col == 1)
                 scalar_product(matrix[i].data[0], &matrix[i + 1]); //Multiplication of Scalar per matrix
             else {                 
                 matrix[i + 1] = multiply(&matrix[i], &matrix[i + 1]);
                 matrix[i + 2] = multiply(&matrix[i + 1], &matrix[i + 2]);
             }
             break;
         }       
    }

    printf("=\n");
    print_matrix(&matrix[id]); /* Print the result */
    free(matrix);
}

struct m multiply(struct m *A, struct m *B) { 
    size_t i, j, k;
    struct m C;
    C.data = malloc(sizeof(double) * A->row * B->col);

    C.row = A->row;
    C.col = B->col;

    for (i = 0; i < C.row; i++)
        for (j= 0 ; j < C.col; j++)
            C.data[i * C.col + j] = 0;

    // Multiplying matrix A and B and storing in C.
    for (i = 0; i < A->row; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < B->col; ++j)
            for (k = 0; k < A->col; ++k)
              C.data[i * C.col + j] += A->data[i * A->col + k] * B->data[k * B->col + j];

    return C;
}

void f(double x) {
    double i, f = modf(x, &i);

    if (f < .00001)
        printf("%.f ", i);
    else
        printf("%f ", x);
}

/* printing a Matrix */

void print_matrix(struct m *A) {
     size_t i, j;
     double *tmp = A->data;

     for (i = 0; i < A->row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < A->col; j++) {
            f(*(tmp++));
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

void scalar_product(double scalar, struct m *B) {
     size_t i, j;

     for (i = 0; i < B->row; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < B->col; j++)
           B->data[i * B->col + j] = scalar * B->data[i * B->col + j];
}
```

The expected result is this: https://ideone.com/Z7UtiR

here `argv[2]` is not read so there is enough memory to store all data.

Comment: This should be easy to figure out if you just stepped through the code, line by line, in a debugger. And know how [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) really works.

Answer (score 1):

Your read buffer only has room for `maxc` (ie. `4`) characters :

```
char buf[maxc]; /*to store each lines of file */
```

You then attempt to get a line from the file into that buffer :

```
while (fgets (buf, maxc, fp)){
```

But that buffer is only large enough for 2 characters, followed by a newline, and then a `'\0'` terminator.

Looking at your sample file, the longest line has 4 characters : `"-4 1"`. So, your buffer needs to at least be able to hold 6 (including the newline and `'\0'` terminator).

It's probably better to make your buffer quite a bit larger.

Comment: Actually the buffer is big enough for three characters plus terminator, leaving the newline to be read in the next iteration as an empty line.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : sure, but that doesn't appear to be the desired behavior here - the code won't handle reading an empty line in the second iteration very well.

Comment: thank you for pointing out also that issue, but there must be another problem because the program already worked well even if argv[2]=3 which is less than 4 characters

Comment: @MichaelangeloMeucci : if `argv[2]` is `3`, then `maxc` is `9`. I assume none of the lines in your file has more than 7 characters ?

Comment: @MichaelangeloMeucci : time to follow Someprogrammerdude's advice then, and bring out the debugger.

Comment: you're right I've forgotten I'm doing the square of that value. But the program still doesn't work. I've updated https://ideone.com/Z7UtiR with your correction

Answer (score 0):

The problem is entirely in reading the arrays.

The `maxc = 4` and the buffer `char buf[maxc];` has place only for 3 characters and terminating character.

So `fgets (buf, maxc, fp)`:

- on the first will read `buf = "1 2"` (3 characters and zero byte)
- on the second will read `buf = "\n"` (1 newline character, fgets terminates)
- then reads `buf = "2 3"`
- then reads `buf = "\n"`
- `buf = "*\n"`
- `buf = "-4 "`
- and so on

Because of the empty line, inside this code snipped:

```
    else /* read integers in a line into d */
    {
        while (sscanf (p + off, "%lf%n", d, &n) == 1) {
            d++;
            if(nrow == 0)
                ncol++;
            off += n;
        }
        nrow++;
        off = 0;
    }
```

The variable `nrow` will be incremented 4 times (2 times for rows, and 2 times for empty lines with only newlines read), which will be 2 times too many. The second matrix will have 1 column, because you will read only `-4` from the line, so your `while(sscanf` loop will scan only one number, so `ncol` will be only 1.

Your fix you posted in the comment is invalid, because you only increased buffer size, but didn't increase the `size` argument you pass to `fgets`. If you did `char buf[2*maxc];` you also should `fgets (buf, 2 * maxc, fp)`, which will "fix" the current problem. I would rather re-write the whole thing or rather write `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]), fp)` to accommodate future changes.

Don't use [VLAs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) ex. `char buf[maxc];`. For simplicity you can use arbitrary long buffer for the line, ex. `#define LINE_MAX 1024` and `char buf[LINE_MAX]` and then `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]), file)`. Or use or rewrite function that will dynamically resize memory and read line, like [GNUs getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).